# moving an image over canvas in android (just like photowonder app)

Tags: android

I'm trying to move an image over canvas so that I can postion it at my preferred location with a preferred size on canvas. I'm now able to place the image at a predefined location on the canvas but I need to give control to user to move it on canvas as per requirement. Please look in to photowonder app to get a clear picture of my question, they gave a feature to add accessories on an image and user can place the accessory at their prefered location.

Answer (score 0):

put your position variables global.
implement touchListener or whatever and update these global variables.
in onDraw use these position variables.